# Does Testflight app override App store app completely?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ipad, testflight

I had built an app which is already available in the app store with version 1.0. This app has local database (i.e. SQLite). Now I am working on next Version (i.e 1.1) and in this Version I have added a new table to my local DB. With this the development is complete.

Now, using testFlight I am performing Internal Testing.

Let's consider two Scenarios:

Case 1:
On my device, I had freshly installed the beta build version 1.1 from testFlight. Once installed, I checked my local DB and found that my local DB is updated with the newly added table.
So this is working fine.

Case 2:
Let's consider a scenario Wherein on my device I am running my app store build  i.e version 1.0 and now I am installing the beta build from Testflight. Once clicked on install button I get a message "Do you want to update the existing app" and by clicking on the ok button the beta build which is version 1.1 is installed on the app.
But when I checked my local DB I found that the database is not updated with the new table. i.e. It's still showing the older database into the app.

Why only my local database is not updated in the second scenario?

Does testFlight build do not override complete app store build along with local DB?

Comment: For that you have to clear data or remove app data 
because when you first execute app your DB copied @ document dir location and after update you execute it the condition checked that id .sqlite available @ doc dir it gets yes so it will not copy new DB

Comment: so you have to clear app data or remove the condition in appDidFinishLaunching method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to really test migration process on production you have to install your app with Itunes because TestFlight or the build process via xCode does not completely override the App.

> Install an ad hoc distribution of an archived build of the update using iTunes on a device that already has the old version of the app installed.

[Test your App with Itunes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html)

I had similar issue with CoreData. I had to make a migration of my DB, and I was unable to test the real scenario of updating the App.

The only true test was :

- Have the old app (from the actual store) installed on the phone.
- Install your new App with Itunes with an Ad-hoc distribution.

Comment: @Nilesh Joshi, any news?